# Doubts about http method AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, request

I implemented a request using AngularJs, but when my server returns badrequest to the client the parameter data of the error function is empty.

```
$http({
  method: args.method,
  url: URL+'/'+args.url,
  data: JSON.stringify(args.data),
  headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
responseType: 'json'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(headers);
    console.log(config);
});
```

But when i use jquery request it works.

```
$.ajax({
        url: URL+"/"+args.url,
        data: JSON.stringify(args.data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: args.method})
    .done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
         ;
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
        if (xhr.status == 400) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }

    });
```

Output Jquery Ajax:

> Testing

How can I get the return of the Post method when the server returns badrequest by angularJS function?

Comment: You need to understand that the `error` callback is used to tell the user about any errors in the `$http` service itself or the backend, now the way you have to tell the `$http` object about the error is to use the HTTP status codes (http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html). 

Now, you have told me that jQuery works; can you show us a little bit of your backend? I mean, just where you make the request fail?

Comment: Ty for your answer. My backend was build in java language. This is my backend returning `Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(message).build();`. The `message` parameter is the parameter what I would like to get. The `message` contains the login error ('invalid password').

Comment: Depending on whether your web Api call is a get or post, it will either require the params or data property to be populated, when you want to pass data to the call

Comment: it's a Post Method, even when I returned the code '200' to the client, the data params is stil null.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong as I don't know your backend structure, but as far as I remember, AngularJS' `$http` service **does not** pass 4 parameters to either of the callbacks: it just passes one.

Quoting Angular's documentation on [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Furthermore, the documentation goes on to define the `response` object:

> The response object has these properties:
>
> **data** – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the
>   transform functions.
>
> **status** – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
>
> **headers** – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
>
> **config** – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate
>    the request.
>
> **statusText** – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

So, one of the errors can be that you aren't giving it the right call-back; it's a very trivial issue in vanilla JavaScript, but I have experienced that in the past with both: Angular and EmberJS.

Try and get the `status` of the response to check is the backend is returning the correct error response code at all. If it is, then there is a problem with the status parsing engine in Angular.

As far as I remember, there were a couple of these cases, but they were fixed. Lastly, try using the lastest **stable** build of AngularJS and check if the error is still there.

Comment: Ty for your answer, but I already read the documentation and I tried their solution, but still didn't work. =(

Comment: When i use jquery method it works. The version of the Angular Framework was downloaded using `ionic start` command.

Comment: So, this error is occurring on mobile phones, I guess?

Comment: I'm using the `ionic server` command to simulate. I created a login view and I would like to get the badrequest answer.

Comment: Try to use the same code without using `ionic`, i.e., test is **out** of Ionic, then you'll see if there's a conflict with `ngCordova`.